# Creating a number pyramid by iteration

Tags: loops, for-loop, if-statement, iteration, pyramid

I am trying to make a number pyramid, but have some problem to find the right conditions.

```
int n = scanner.nextInt();
int a;
for(int q = 1; q <= n; q++)
{
    for(int space = 0; space < n-q; space++){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    a = 1;
    for(int p = 1; p <= q; p++){
        if((p <= q / 2 && p != 1)){                         
            a++;
        }
        else if((p != 1) && (p > q / 2 + 1)){
            a--;
        }
        System.out.print(a+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

It creates a proper pyramid, but the uneven rows stop to increase to early.

Supposed outcome:

```
    1
   1 1
  1 2 1
 1 2 2 1
1 2 3 2 1
```

The outcome of my code is

```
         1
        1 1
       1 1 0
      1 2 2 1
     1 2 2 1 0
    1 2 3 3 2 1
   1 2 3 3 2 1 0
  1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1
 1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 0
1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: your number pyramid is called Pascal triangle...

Comment: Well no it aint

Comment: Sorry for downrating, but this look like we should do your homework :-)

Comment: To ask  a good question which other people will find desciptive and useful later on if they encounter the same programming issue

Comment: @MelissaLoos: Output "with the condition" and output "without the condition" is a good start and all.  But I guess the next step here would be some debugging on your part.  As you define each piece of logic in your code, when you step through that logic in the debugger, how specifically does it not to what's expected?  Is this a problem of the code not doing what you expect it to?  Or is this a problem with a math puzzle that you didn't find the answer to?  We can help with the former, if you can narrow down the specific operation that isn't performing as expected.

Comment: @MelissaLoos you are right, not the Pascal triangle, my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it works:

```
int number = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    int x = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < (number + i); j++) {
        if (j < number - i - 1) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        } else {
            System.out.print(x);
            if (j < (number - 1)) {
                x++;
            } else {
                x--;
            }  
        }
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
}
```